# In QTP 11 ,how to test many buttons with a only one JavaButton ?

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I would like to test the buttons of my "Block diagram" is a java application, I added one JavaButton in my object repository and i want to test the exsitances of buttons and if they are not enabled by default.
I have in the properties of JavaButton "label and attached text" ,i used a regular expression but i can't test all the buttons (I2C1, I2C2, etc..) As in the snapshot with only one JavaButton .

I would like to test all buttons:
JavaWindow ("Untitled MicroXplorer *"). JavaButton ("I2C1").exist(1)
JavaWindow ("Untitled MicroXplorer *"). JavaButton ("I2C2").exist(1)

but I don't want to add all the JavaButtons in my object repository, i want only aone JavaButton with a regular expression to the test.
Thank you in advance.

[Snapshot bloc diagram click here](http://www.imagup.com/npic/1178728331.html)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using any `JavaButton` objects for that, you `ChildObjects` to get all the objects that match your description

```
Set Desc = Description.Create()
Desc("micclass").Value = "JavaButton"
Desc("label").Value = "I2C\d+" ' I'm not sure if label is the correct property...
Set Buttons = JavaWindow.ChildObjects(Desc)
For i = 0 To Buttons.Count - 1
    Buttons(i)._Whatever_
Next
```

You *can* use a single `JavaButton` in the object repository and then do a `SetTOProperty` on the `index` property but the `ChildObjects` approach is more natural.

Comment: I did just that is it works!

myLabel = "GPIO"
If JavaWindow ("MicroXplorer Untitled"). JavaButton ("label: =" & myLabel). Exist Then
     msgbox "Woei! Javawindow A label with" & myLabel & "exists!"
else
msgbox "Fail! Javawindow A label with" & myLabel & "not exists!"
End if